# Return rows with column not equals null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a working Spring Boot application, I'm vey new to JPA/Hibernate and I'm trying to retrieve results having one of the fields containing no null values. Right now I am getting everything including nulls.

It is `phone_number_id` that I don't want it to be null. I added `nullable=false` but it looks like it has no effect on retrievals.

What do I need to do to get only columns which have no null occurrences of `phone_number_id`

My Model

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Ad.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Ad a")
public class Ad implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="ad_content")
    private String adContent;

    @Column(name="ad_title")
    private String adTitle;

    @Column(name="ad_url")
    private String adUrl;

    private Integer age;

    @Column(name="post_id")
    private Long postId;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to City
    @ManyToOne
    private City city;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PhoneNumber
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="phone_number_id", nullable=false)
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AdPhoto
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ad")
    private List<AdPhoto> adPhotos;

    public Ad() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAdContent() {
        return this.adContent;
    }

    public void setAdContent(String adContent) {
        this.adContent = adContent;
    }

    public String getAdTitle() {
        return this.adTitle;
    }

    public void setAdTitle(String adTitle) {
        this.adTitle = adTitle;
    }

    public String getAdUrl() {
        return this.adUrl;
    }

    public void setAdUrl(String adUrl) {
        this.adUrl = adUrl;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getPostId() {
        return this.postId;
    }

    public void setPostId(Long postId) {
        this.postId = postId;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public List<AdPhoto> getAdPhotos() {
        return this.adPhotos;
    }

    public void setAdPhotos(List<AdPhoto> adPhotos) {
        this.adPhotos = adPhotos;
    }

    public AdPhoto addAdPhoto(AdPhoto adPhoto) {
        getAdPhotos().add(adPhoto);
        adPhoto.setAd(this);

        return adPhoto;
    }

    public AdPhoto removeAdPhoto(AdPhoto adPhoto) {
        getAdPhotos().remove(adPhoto);
        adPhoto.setAd(null);

        return adPhoto;
    }
```

My repository

```
@Repository
public interface AdRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Ad, Long> {

}
```

and my Service class

```
@Service
public class AdService {
    private final static int PAGESIZE = 3;

    @Autowired
    AdRepository adRepository;

    public Iterable<Ad> findAllAds() {
        return adRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Ad> getPage(int pageNumber) {
        PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGESIZE, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");

        return adRepository.findAll(request).getContent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
@Repository
public interface AdRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Ad, Long> {
   List<Ad> findByPhoneNumberIsNull();
}
```

You don't need the NameQuery you get the findAll for free from PagingAndSortingRepository

See the full documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details)

Comment: Shouldn't I be using `List<Ad> findByPhoneNumberIsNotNull(PageRequest request);` since I want not null and I'm passing it `PageRequest request` from the AdService class?

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="phone_number_id", nullable=false)
private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
```

the `nullable = false` specifies the not null constraint on the DB level.

If you also want to validate the content on the application level you cand use the `@NotNull` annotation (which I also recommend).

By doing this you do not allow a Ad entity to exist without a phone number. If however the phone number is optional, then use the answer provided by @Essex Boy